# Navigation Controller & Tab Controller

Tags: ios, swift, tabs, controller, navigation

I'm new to iOS development and I'm feeling kind of lost here.

I'm working on an app idea where I have login/sign up (using Parse) embedded in Navigation controller and then once the user has logged in I want to integrate tab controller as the app interface should be tabbed.

But for some reason it doesn't work properly.

Here's what my storyboard look like:

[image: Storyboard]

The problem is that once I login and it redirects me to the Tab controller I see this:

[image: Screen]

I have NO idea why. Any ideas?

**EDIT:** Added original images to message

**UPDATE**: I believe I've screwed up the project somehow. In the very beginning. I've recreated everything from scratch, Added Navigation controllers and now the problem is gone and it everything loads the way it should be!

Comment: what have you tried until now? Please provide some code fragments where you think you have a problem with...

Comment: Well, I don't think its the code. The 3 VC in the Tab Controller has no code whatsoever. I just have created each scene along with the view controllers that should control each scene but that's it. There's no code in any code. Just basic blank Cocoa Touch Class for iOS.

I thought it could be something related to the segue between the Login button and the Tab nav controller. The segue from the Login button to the tab nav controller is "Show"

Could the Navigation Controller mess up with the tab controller somehow?

Comment: ok then. I've updated your question to include your images directly which makes it easier to read...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Segue between SignIn controller and TabBar controller must be "Present Modally"

And then if you want use navigation controller after TabBar controller, you must add new navigation controller between your tabs and TabBarController!

If you want to have there tabs with NavigationController, you must add three Navigation Controller...

this is quick Demo for you! [Download here!](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bzx5SwSXW9UqelMzVFkzNGhMOTA/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Actually, it's the opposite. I'm using Navigation controller and then tab controller. And it's working. Meaning, I login, I'm sent to the Home tab of the Tab bar controller. 

The problem is that I see this grey area in the middle of the screen and I don't see my tabs which are on the bottom (they are also working, I just don't see them and I'm clicking blindly here - I've put labels on each VC in the tabs so I know it actually works!) 

I've checked the segue to "Present Modally".

Comment: Segue between TabBarController and Your tabs are Relationship Segue: View controllers?

Comment: I create demo project for you, please download! link in answer!

Comment: Dmitry, thank you for the effort. I've integrated the Nav controllers just like you did. The problem is not in that though. I see ridiculous stuff and I don't know if its Xcode bug or what. 

I can login, then I'm sent to the Tab Bar Navigation, just like it supposed to. 

Then I see screens like those:

http://puu.sh/gLnbe/71c35924e5.png
http://puu.sh/gLnnH/1c9c3ff61b.png

I have NO idea what's causing that! 

Even in the storyboard itself, I don't see it properly. I have these grey bars instead of the the tab bars. THIS is the real issue here:

http://puu.sh/gLnE0/ae719f5895.png